# networkx color based on Label clustering

Tags: python, networkx

I have a link base data which I did clustering label for each of them and the data look like this: the id_1 and id_2 are linked to each others and the label is the cluster number for each link.

```
id_1,id_2,label
0,18427,1
1,21708,1
1,22208,1
1,22171,1
1,6829,1
1,16590,1
1,20135,1
1,8894,1
1,15785,1
1,10281,1
etc..
```

and I use `networkx` library to graph the line between them.

Is there a way to color the data Nodes based on cluster label as we do in the `seaborn` library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nx.draw` has plenty of arguments that allow you to customize the generated plot. In this case you want to set a `edge_color` that depends on the `label` attribute. I've modified the `labels` a bit here to better illustrate the point.

To reproduce your example I've generated the graph from the edgelist as a pandas dataframe, which makes it very simple. Since I've set `edge_attr=True`, the `label` will be an attribute. We can thus save it as a dictionary using `nx.get_edge_attributes`.

Then we can set the edge color using `edge_color=list(labels.values())` with a `cmap` of choice and plot the graph as follows:

```
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='id_1', target='id_2', edge_attr=True)
cmap = cm.get_cmap('viridis', max(labels.values()))
labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'label')

plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, 
        edgelist=list(labels.keys()), 
        edge_color=list(labels.values()),
        edge_cmap= plt.cm.summer, 
        node_color='lightgreen', 
        node_size=1000, width=2)
```

[image]

---

Set up -

```
s = StringIO('''
id_1,id_2,label
0,18427,1
1,21708,1
1,22208,3
1,22171,4
1,6829,1
1,16590,2
1,20135,3
1,8894,2
1,15785,2
1,10281,2
''')
df = pd.read_csv(s, delim_whitespace=False, sep=',')
```

Comment: it works fine thank you :D  but is there a way to color the link and the node not only the link ?

Comment: Yes, instead of setting `node_color=somecolor`, set it to `list(labels.values())`, like `edge_color` @RAbeeq

Comment: already did and choose (accept this answer) thank you <3

Comment: it give me this error ` name 'labels' is not defined`. what labels.values()) mean ?

Comment: `labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'label')`, its in the code @RAbeeq

Comment: okay last question i promise can i put the dataframe in the StringIO() function ?
for example if the dataframe above called df='the values' can I do stringIO(df)

Comment: No, I just used that to parse your dataframe above, which is a string. But use `pd.read_csv` or some equivalent, depending on the source. You'll find plenty of posts of how to read data into a pandas dataframe @RAbeeq